# How to receive a JSON from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to return an object from an AJAX call.

I've got an AJAX call that looks like:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
          //success                  
          var object = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "newjsp.jsp", true);
xhttp.send();
```

and a JSP file:

```
<%@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "value");
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
%>
```

After a test i got this error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 61
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. **Look** at the value of `this.responseTest`. Find out what is at position 61 and why it makes it invalid JSON. Then figure out where your server side code is generating that.

Comment: I've done a lot of them before asking, but i found the error: i've forgot to invoke the toString method to a date object. Thanks a lot for your help.